# Creating project with forcedroid not runnable

Tags: mobilesdk, sfdcmobilesdk-android

I'm trying to get started with creating an android hybrid app so I followed all the steps an create my new project through the forcedroid utility, however, when I try to execute this default scaffolding, the app fails to load in the emulator and LogCat shows that is has failed on permissions. Adding the missing permissions doesn't solve the problem as it now just ges to a black screen and locks there. When I try to hit any 'hardware' button on the emulator I get a DroidGap nullpointer exception. The sample apps work like a charm, and I just can't figure out what's different that makes them run and my own app fail.

UPDATE: Found out there was a missing mergemanifest.enabled parameter in my project properties. This has solved the permissions issue but the app still comes up as a black screen and does nothing while it has an index.html in the www folder that should be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, so apart from the mergemanifest parameter, I also needed to add a `<string name="account_type">` element to my app's strings.xml. I used the same value as the package name and everything works as expected now